# What does 旗舰店 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

旗舰 is flagship, but 旗舰店 is not a shop where a flagship is on sale, right? If it is a shop in relation to flagship, the meaning is not very clear. Because a headquarter is a better choice for that. So what is the real meaning of this phrase?

Comment: it is official shop, (not reseller).

Answer (score 2):

旗舰店 is just a direct translation of flagship store, which is used in english like this one: [5th Avenue](http://visit5thavenue.com/category/flagship-stores/).

Comment: For additional information, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flagship-store

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the online Dictionary of International Trade:

"In retail business the designation of flagship is given to a retailer’s primary location, a store in a prominent location, a chain’s largest store, the store that holds or sells the highest volume of merchandise, a retailer’s most well-known location, a chain’s first retail outlet, a store location with decor or merchandise mix that is distinctly different from the rest of the chain, or the store location in a chain which carries the most high-priced merchandise catering to the most upscale customers."

Note that in English, a flagship store does not sell flagships either. And it differs from the headquarter in that a flagship store is a retail store whereas headquarter is usually offices where business decisions regarding the chain are made. Both in Chinese and in English, the word "flagship -旗舰" is used figuratively.

Answer (score 0):

in e-commercials,like taobao's tmall,it means it is the brand's official e-shop.for the realistic shop,it means it is the mainly shop of the brand